# HttpClient Request Content

Tags: c#, httpclient, adfs

I'm trying to use `HttpClient` to get a token from AD FS, then log into a `SharePoint` site.  I've got the first part working in that I can successfully post credentials to ADFS and get a token in the response.  I'm struggling with the second part.  The way AD FS handles this is to reply with a 200 (OK) after login.  The body of the response has a hidden form which contains the token and destination URL.  In a browser, the form is submitted automatically with JavaScript.  But `HttpClient` doesn't execute JS, so the process stops.

My question: is it possible to just take the `.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` and add it to another post request?  I could use HTML Agility Pack to extract the form values, then add them to a new request as a key/value array (that's how I'm posting my credentials to ADFS), but I'm wondering if there is an easier way, since I have the form content already available in the response from AD FS.

Thanks!

Update: I ended up going this route, using HTML Agility Pack.

```
// load into HTML Agility Pack
HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("form");
var adfsPage = new HtmlDocument();
adfsPage.LoadHtml(formContent);

HtmlNode formNode = adfsPage.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//form")[0];
// loop through each input and add it to the key/value array
foreach (HtmlNode node in formNode.Elements("input"))
  {
    HtmlAttribute value = node.Attributes["value"];
    HtmlAttribute name = node.Attributes["name"];
    if (value != null)
      {
        form.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(name.Value, value.Value));
      }
      Console.WriteLine("Key: " + name.Value);
      Console.WriteLine("Value: " + value.Value);
  }
```